# RecyclerView scroll/state position is not automatically restored

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

As I understand it, RecyclerView scroll position should automatically restore on rotation. When I debug, I can see the RecyclerView view_state is automatically saved and available without any code intervention on my part. The problem is, when I rotate the device, the RecyclerView scroll position is not restored automatically as expected. Please know that I have tried numerous suggestions found here on stackoverflow, from reordering my code; to moving code to onActivityCreated; to checking if adapter is null; to other items I cannot recall. I have also review [this](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/0fe38930be6929e59ce228d4473d7b29) simple app to compare. The big differences between that app and mine is: my data is retrieved asynchronously with a Retrofit call; I use viewmodel, repository, and livedata. I'm new to all of this, going through the Udacity Nanodegree. I've been working on this daily for over two weeks with no resolution in sight.

I would post snippets of my code but I would have to post MainActivity, fragment, Adapter, and layout files, well basically almost the whole app. I thought it much easier to just post a link to my source [here](https://github.com/mpadilla2/Udacity-Popular-Movies). Please let me know if the link is sufficient. I can always post an edit with a snippet of code for the resolution.

Please do let me know if there is anything else needed from me.

Comment: Please don't just link to your project off-site. You need to create and include a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for that. I'll work on it and update my question.